# Iterating through rows in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am having an issue applying some maths to my dataframe

Current df:

| name | lastConnected | check |
| --- | --- | --- |
| test1 | 1647609274746 | Connection |
| test2 | 1647609274785 | Connection |
| test3 | 1647000000000 | Connection |
| test4 | 1647609274756 | Connection |

Desired df: i now want to create a new column and check if server is still online

| name | lastConnected | check |
| --- | --- | --- |
| test1 | 1647609274746 | Connection |
| test2 | 1647609274785 | Connection |
| test3 | 1647000000000 | No connection |
| test4 | 1647609274756 | Connection |

current code:

```
def checkServer():
        for index, row in df.iterrows():
                timeNow = int((time.time_ns) // 1000000)
                lastSeenTime = row['lastConnected']
                timeDifference = currentTime - lastSeenTime
                if timeDifference > 5000:
                        df['check'] = "No connection"
                else:
                        df['check'] = "Connection"
        return df
```

My issue:

As you can see in my current dataframe it gives Connection to them all even though test3 should have No connection. From my troubleshooting, i printed the  timeDifference into each row and i got the same time difference even though its all got different times. As a result I think my for loop might be the issue.

Use this site to get current time in miliseconds:  currentmillis.com

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Can you explain your logic please?

Comment: So i want to get the current timestamp in miliseconds and compare to the lastConnected time.

If over 5000 then say No connection else connected.

E.g https://currentmillis.com/ 
Current timestamp: 1647612255595

If 1647612255595 (current timestamp)- 1647609274746(timestamp for test1) is greater than 500 then check = No connection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you expect:

```
df['check'] = np.where(pd.Timestamp.today().timestamp() * 1000 - df['lastConnected'] > 5000,
                       'No connection', 'Connection')
print(df)

# Output
    name  lastConnected          check
0  test1  1647609274746     Connection
1  test2  1647609274785     Connection
2  test3  1647000000000  No connection
3  test4  1647609274756     Connection
```

---

**Old answer**

Use `np.where`:

```
df['check'] = np.where(df['lastConnected'].diff().abs().gt(5000),
                       'No connection', 'Connection')
print(df)

# Output
    name  lastConnected          check
0  test1        1647609     Connection
1  test2        1647579     Connection
2  test3        1640009  No connection
```

Comment: I updated my answer. Can you check it please?

Answer (score 2):

IIUC, don't use `iterrows` but a vectorial function:

```
N = 5000
df.loc[df['lastConnected'].diff().lt(-N), 'check'] = 'No connection'
```

or to create the column from sratch:

```
N = 5000
df['check'] = np.where(df['lastConnected'].diff().lt(-N),
                       'No connection', 'connection')
```

output:

```
    name  lastConnected          check
0  test1        1647609     Connection
1  test2        1647579     Connection
2  test3        1640009  No connection
```